# mySQL query returns 3 columns, I want to get values from one column concatenated into comma separated string

Tags: mysql, string, concatenation

I need to get the values from the meta_value column that have "shipping" in the corresponding meta_key column and concatenate them into a comma separated row.

I'm a bit of a noob to SQL so please be gentle.

[image]

My current query is this:

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.post_ID, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value, wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_status 
FROM wp_postmeta 
CROSS JOIN wp_posts 
WHERE wp_postmeta.post_ID= wp_posts.ID 
  AND wp_posts.post_status LIKE 'wc-processing' 
  AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%shipping%' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '_order_total')
```

Comment: can you please provide some snippets of your code?

Comment: You don't want a cross join (which is also called a cartesian product). That gives you the number of records in the first table X the number of records in the 2nd table. You probably want an inner join, which gives you matching records. FYI, the remaining joins are left, right and full. There's a nice Venn diagram out there: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: What will be expected output, as per your given sample data ?

Answer (score 0):

So, here's your query (note how I write it - I find that good formatting of SQL helps to read it):

```
SELECT  
    wp_postmeta.post_ID, 
    wp_postmeta.meta_key, 
    wp_postmeta.meta_value, 
    wp_posts.ID, 
    wp_posts.post_status 
FROM 
    wp_postmeta 
CROSS JOIN 
    wp_posts 
WHERE 
    wp_postmeta.post_ID = wp_posts.ID 
    AND wp_posts.post_status LIKE 'wc-processing' 
    AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%shipping%' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '_order_total')
```

Here's what I think you want (you use the [MySQL concat function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)):

```
Select
   concat(
        wp_postmeta.meta_key, ',',
        wp_postmeta.meta_value
    ) as formatted_row
FROM 
    wp_postmeta 
INNER JOIN 
    wp_posts 
ON
    wp_postmeta.post_ID = wp_posts.ID 
WHERE 
    wp_posts.post_status LIKE 'wc-processing' 
    AND (
           wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%shipping%' 
           OR wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '_order_total'
        )
```

Also note: Single quotes and double quotes mean different things in [different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to join the strings together. As has been pointed out by @kermit, you should use an `INNER JOIN` not a `CROSS JOIN`. I am presuming you want to keep the order total separate from the shipping details, so you will need to use conditional aggregation as well. This query should do what you want:

```
SELECT m.post_ID
     , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN m.meta_key LIKE '%shipping%' THEN m.meta_value END) AS shipping_info
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = '_order_total' THEN m.meta_value ELSE 0 END) AS order_total
FROM wp_postmeta m
INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON m.post_ID = p.ID 
WHERE p.post_status LIKE 'wc-processing' 
  AND (m.meta_key LIKE '%shipping%' OR m.meta_key LIKE '_order_total')
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick its a bit more involved than on sql server but easy enough

```
create table if not exists test(col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(10), col3 varchar(10));
insert into test values("this","is","test");
select concat(col1,",",col2,",",col3) as csvCol from test
```

delivers

```
csvCol
this,is,test
```

Comment: Apologies all for my lack of response. I got snowed under at work and haven't had time to test these out. I will endeavour to do so in the next couple of days and will respond then. Thanks for all your help.